# prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Given $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a \neq0$.

Need to prove that  $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$.

So i know that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$ so $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1} = a$ for the getting $1$, but how do i prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We assume that $a>0$.  Then, for any given $\epsilon>0$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that whenever $n>N$,

$$a-a\epsilon/4 <a_n<a+a\epsilon/4$$

and

$$a-a\epsilon/4 <a_{n+1}<a+a\epsilon/4$$

Now, if we take $n$ so large that $a/2\le a_n\le 3a/2$, we can write

$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1\right|=\frac{|a_{n+1}-a_n|}{|a_n|}\le \epsilon$$

and we are done!

Answer (score 2):

For any $k\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0,1\}$, $\lim_{n\to +\infty} a_n = a\neq 0$ implies that for any $n$ big enough we have:
$$ \left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right) a \leq a_n \leq \left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right) a, $$
that implies:
$$ \frac{k-1}{k+1}\leq \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq \frac{k+1}{k-1}.$$
By letting $k\to +\infty$ the claim follows.

Answer (score 1):

Write $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1+\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_n}$. You can use standard limit facts to show that the second part goes to zero.

Comment: i meant as an epsilon proof.

Comment: OK, so use epsilon-delta to show that $\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_n}$ goes to zero; you can make $a_{n+1}-a_n$ arbitrarily close to zero by making $n$ large and $a_n$ arbitrarily close to $a\neq 0$.